# Discord.js - Ping a Role using Role ID

Tags: discord.js

I want to ping a role using ID, so far i have tried this:

```
 function prayer() {
      let myChannel = 'channel ID'
      client.channels.cache.get(myChannel).send("Mentioning. <@707335030002942033>");
  }
```

But all it does it print the <@707335030002942033> and not the role itself. Is this command deprecated?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To ping a role you will need <@&"roleID">

Comment: The great thing about this is that it works for other languages too (with their respective APIs).

Answer (score 4):

Type `<@&(role id here)>` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is use <@&[roleid]>.

Example:

```
<@&757133230280409177>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use <@&role-id> or you can do `role.mention`

Answer (score -2):

try to put @ outside of <>, mayby it will work

Comment: This will cause the message to not be treated like a mention at all